# Automatically convert JSON to Object on Flask Request

Tags: java, python, json, spring-mvc, flask

In Spring MVC + Jackson (Java), I can have this:

**My Object (Java)**

```
public class Project {

   private long id;
   private String self;
   private String key;
   private String name;

   //Getters and Setters
}
```

**Spring MVC Controller**

```
...
@RequestMapping(value="/doSomething", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doSomething(@RequestBody Project project) {
    System.out.println(project.getName());
    return "myPage";
}
...
```

Then, I can send a json like:

```
{"id": "exampleId", "name": "exampleName","self": "url","key": "key"}
```

And automatically it converts to my object. On Python, I have my object class. There's something in Flask that I could call:

**Flask Controller**

```
@app.route('/doSomething', methods=['POST'])
def do_something(project):
    print project.name
    return "myPage"
```

**My Object (Python)**

```
class Project():

    id=None        
    name=None
    url=None
    key=None
```

---

Essentially, I wanna receive my JSON on Flask and already converts to my Object. I wanna avoid from doing this:

```
class Project(object):
  def __init__(self, id, url, name, key):
    self.id = id
    self.url = url
    self.name = name
    self.key = key
...
import json
my_json = json.loads(request.data)
user = Project(**j)
```

This way, I'll have to override init from all my objects. Or this:

```
project = json.loads('{"__type__": "Project", "name": "project", "key": "key"}')
print project['name']
print project['key']
```

Not good either because it's not my object, it's a dict.

Is this possible? Or I have to choose one of these?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, I don't think you can avoid adding a constructor if you have to use a class in Python.

The other option would be to use [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). They are like tuples but with field names. Either way, you can sort of simulate what you want using a decorator

Ex:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Project = namedtuple('Project', 'id url name key')
```

Now you can do something like this in your view handler:

```
# This decorator takes the class/namedtuple to convert any JSON
# data in incoming request to. 
def convert_input_to(class_):
    def wrap(f):
        def decorator(*args):
            obj = class_(**request.get_json())
            return f(obj)
        return decorator
    return wrap

@app.route('/doSomething', methods=['POST'])
@convert_input_to(Project)
def do_something(project):
    print project.name
    return "myPage"
```

Also see [flask.Request.get_json](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request.get_json) and make sure `'Content-Type'` is set to `'application/json'`

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. I just needed to adjust the namedtuple class to use methods later, so it looks like: `class Project(namedtuple('Project', 'id url name key')):

     def __new__(cls, id=None, name=None, url=None, key=None):
        return super(Project, cls).__new__(cls, id, name, url, key)`

Comment: Correct class: `class Project(namedtuple('Project', 'id name url key')): def __new__(cls, id=None, name=None, url=None, key=None): return super(Project, cls).__new__(cls, id, name, url, key)`

Comment: I know that the Django Rest Framework will do this sort of thing automatically (no need to construct all you objects yourself once you have the models). Is there really no way to do the same in Flask?