# insert new record dynamically depending on Table Name (postgres DB using SQLalchemy)

Tags: json, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I would like to know how to write JSON object into tables which depends on the tableName.

I know how to write to table explictly (see below).

I don't know how to write it such a way that I can disregard the table name. Just write to the table dynamically. With that, I don't have to write new codes every time there is a new table. the code below demo two tables (Customer, Project) with two set of codes.

Please help!

```
JsonA = {'tableName': 'Customer','firstName' : 'Jennifer','lastName' : 'Seik','number' : '3407'}
dataA = Customer(firstName =  JsonA.get('firstName'),
    lastName = JsonA.get('lastName'),
    number = JsonA.get('number')
    )
db.session.add(dataA)
db.session.commit()

JsonB = {'tableName': 'Project','projectName' : 'foo','projectNumber' : '123','number' : '3407','projectDays':'60'}
dataB = Project(projectName =  JsonB.get('projectName'),
    projectNumber = JsonB.get('projectNumber'),
    number = JsonB.get('number'),
    projectDays = JsonB.get('projectDays')
    )
db.session.add(dataB)
db.session.commit()
```

I am using:
SQLAlchemy==1.4.23
Flask==2.0.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically convert JSON to Object on Flask Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717754/automatically-convert-json-to-object-on-flask-request)

Comment: hi Zegarek, thank you for the response. I am not sure if it answered my question.